# Trouble with Grid and StackPanel - Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

OK, I'm having issues properly using a `ScrollViewer` (containing an `ItemsControl`) inside a `StackPanel`.

The thing is the scrolling works, however :

- No matter how much the user scrolls down, **the bottom lines of the tables are not visible**
- When scrolling is... "released", **the table pops back up**...

---

```
<ScrollViewer Height="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="ResTable">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.10*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding [num]}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding [A]}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding [B]}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding [C]}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Any ideas?

---

**P.S.**

- I've had a look at some of the other answers to similar issues, but none seems to be working...
- My main idea is to **display a table, with a fixed header**, and scrollable contents (populated via Bindings) - ok, and there are also a couple of things on the top of the page (apart from the table I mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue is that you should probably use parent element like *Grid*, **not *StackPanel***, because *StackPanel* has its drawbacks when resizing child items with scrolls and so on.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!-- Put headers in Grid.Row="0" -->

<!-- Put Scrollviewer in Grid.Row="1" --> 

</Grid>
```

Also `Height="Auto"` attribute can be removed from *ScrollViewer*, you might want to use `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` for item to take all the available space. I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That's exactly what I did to fix it **just right now**. And when I got back here I saw your reply. Great one, of course. And it works! Thanks, buddy! Spot on! :-)